# how to access the subscribe within forkJoin while testing

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following method:

```
setup() { 
const observables$ = {
      summary1: this.service1.getSummary(data),
      summary2: this.service2.getSummary()};
    forkJoin(observables$).subscribe((res) => {
      if(res.summary1) {
        // perform some operation
      }
      if(res.summary2) {
        this.value = res.summary; // this needs to be checked
      }
    })
  }
}
```

The test I wrote is unable to reach subscribe block of forkJoin:

```
it('setup()', async() => {
    const expectedData = mockData;
    const summary1spy = jest.spyOn(service1, 'getSummary').mockReturnValue(of(expectedData));
    const summary2spy = jest.spyOn(service2, 'getSummary').mockReturnValue(of());
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.setup();
    expect(summary1spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(summary2spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // the above 2 lines succeed
    // but the code within subscribe is not reached

  });
```

Trying to subscribe to `setup` does not work as it does not return any observables.

Answer (score 0):

```
component.setup().subscribe(() => {
  expect(summary1spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(summary2spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  done();
});
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.